# HTTP Basic Authentication for Play framework 2.4

Tags: scala, authentication, playframework, playframework-2.4

I am looking some way to make some authentication for my play framework app: I want allow/disallow the whole access to non authenticated users

Is there exists some working module/solution for it? I don't need any forms for auth, just 401 HTTP response for non authenticated users (like Apache .htacccess "AuthType Basic" mode).

Comment: You may want to have a look at the module listing: https://www.playframework.com/modules

Comment: @cchantep _These modules are for the Play 1.x series only and are now read-only._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this filter:

https://github.com/Kaliber/play-basic-authentication-filter

It looks pretty simple to use and configure.

Comment: it was i was looking for: simple and straitforward and without extra features

Answer (score 7):

I've updated Jonck van der Kogel's answer to be more strict in parsing the authorization header, to not fail with ugly exceptions if the auth header is invalid, to allow passwords with ':', and to work with Play 2.6:

So, BasicAuthAction class:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import play.Logger;
import play.Logger.ALogger;
import play.mvc.Action;
import play.mvc.Http;
import play.mvc.Http.Context;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class BasicAuthAction extends Action<Result> {
    private static ALogger log = Logger.of(BasicAuthAction.class);

    private static final String AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";
    private static final String WWW_AUTHENTICATE = "WWW-Authenticate";
    private static final String REALM = "Basic realm=\"Realm\"";

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> call(Context context) {
        String authHeader = context.request().getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
        if (authHeader == null) {
            context.response().setHeader(WWW_AUTHENTICATE, REALM);
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(status(Http.Status.UNAUTHORIZED, "Needs authorization"));
        }

        String[] credentials;
        try {
            credentials = parseAuthHeader(authHeader);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("Cannot parse basic auth info", e);
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(status(Http.Status.FORBIDDEN, "Invalid auth header"));
        }

        String username = credentials[0];
        String password = credentials[1];
        boolean loginCorrect = checkLogin(username, password);

        if (!loginCorrect) {
            log.warn("Incorrect basic auth login, username=" + username);
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(status(Http.Status.FORBIDDEN, "Forbidden"));
        } else {
            context.request().setUsername(username);
            log.info("Successful basic auth login, username=" + username);
            return delegate.call(context);
        }
    }

    private String[] parseAuthHeader(String authHeader) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        if (!authHeader.startsWith("Basic ")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Authorization header");
        }

        String[] credString;
        String auth = authHeader.substring(6);
        byte[] decodedAuth = new Base64().decode(auth);
        credString = new String(decodedAuth, "UTF-8").split(":", 2);
        if (credString.length != 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Authorization header");
        }

        return credString;
    }

    private boolean checkLogin(String username, String password) {
        /// change this
        return username.equals("vlad");
    }
}
```

And then, in controller classes:

```
@With(BasicAuthAction.class)
public Result authPage() {
    String username = request().username();
    return Result.ok("Successful login as user: " + username + "! Here's your data: ...");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also solve this with a play.mvc.Action, like this.

First your Action:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import play.libs.F;
import play.libs.F.Promise;
import play.mvc.Action;
import play.mvc.Http.Context;
import play.mvc.Result;
import util.ADUtil;

public class BasicAuthAction extends Action<Result> {
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION = "authorization";
    private static final String WWW_AUTHENTICATE = "WWW-Authenticate";
    private static final String REALM = "Basic realm=\"yourRealm\"";

    @Override
    public Promise<Result> call(Context context) throws Throwable {
        String authHeader = context.request().getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
        if (authHeader == null) {
            context.response().setHeader(WWW_AUTHENTICATE, REALM);
            return F.Promise.promise(new F.Function0<Result>() {
                @Override
                public Result apply() throws Throwable {
                    return unauthorized("Not authorised to perform action");
                }
            });
        }

        String auth = authHeader.substring(6);
        byte[] decodedAuth = new Base64().decode(auth);
        String[] credString = new String(decodedAuth, "UTF-8").split(":");


        String username = credString[0];
        String password = credString[1];
        // here I authenticate against AD, replace by your own authentication mechanism
        boolean loginCorrect = ADUtil.loginCorrect(username, password);

        if (!loginCorrect) {
            return F.Promise.promise(new F.Function0<Result>() {
                @Override
                public Result apply() throws Throwable {
                    return unauthorized("Not authorised to perform action");
                }
            });
        } else {
            return delegate.call(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Next your annotation:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import play.mvc.With;


@With(BasicAuthAction.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface BasicAuth {
}
```

You can now annotate your controller functions as follows:

```
@BasicAuth
public Promise<Result> yourControllerFunction() {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there's no such solution, reason is simple: usually when devs need to add authorization/authentication stack they build *full* solution.

The easiest and fastest way is using [**HTTP front-end server**](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/HTTPServer) as a reverse-proxy for your application (I'd choose [nginx](http://nginx.org/) for that task, but if you have running Apache on the machine it can be used as well). It will allow you to filter/authenticate the traffic with common server's rules

Additionally it gives you other benefits, i.e.: you can create CDN-like path, so you won't waste your apps' resources for serving public, static assets. You can use load-balancer for redeploying your app without stopping it totally for x minutes, etc.

Comment: Here's the sample config for apache http://bjeanes.com/2009/09/using-apache-as-a-basicauth-proxy-to-an-internal-resource